# how to detect swipe direction android fragmentactivity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I am developing an android app.My class extends FragmentActivity,and i am using a viewpager in my class which has a setonpagechangelistner to detect the swipe from one screen to another.

The problem is, i am not able to detect swipe left and swipe right gesture. Is there a way to detect it?I am trying to trigger an Animation on swipe right (i.e, from page0 to page1).

I am working on this since two days.please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know if the user swiped to prev and next page? Or just if it is moving in a certain direction?

Comment: the direction, left swipe or right swipe by the user.

Comment: how many pages you have and tell me your current page number.

Comment: i have 11 pages. it start with 0 to 11th page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe Direction in ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721539/swipe-direction-in-viewpager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved with this answer [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)
I've attached to viewpager.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener); in the activity where I create the fragment and the viewpager.
Basically in this way

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnPageListener {

List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
private MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_famiglia);

//......

// Gesture detection
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };


fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Page1Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Page2Fragment.class.getName()));
    // creating adapter and linking to view pager
    this.pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(this.pageAdapter);

    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
}

//.....

}
```

and onFling method retrieve the current page with viewPager.getCurrentItem() and perform a specific action only if is the first one.

Hope it helps.