# Swipe Direction in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, direction, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have an Android app that uses ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I however need to add a new feature in which I have to know the swipe direction to move from one fragment view to another, left or right. (i.e, when I swipe left, I would do one thing, and when I swipe right I would do something else).

Please note, I do not need the events to happen AFTER the swipe is over. I have to do those events as the swipe occurs. I thought of using `setOnPageChangeListener()` but it does not tell me swipe direction. Can you advise me please on how to figure out swipe direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue and need to know the direction of the swipe *as it was happening* in order to prevent swiping in a certain direction. Here is how I solved my problem, hopefully it is helpful to someone. I found all of the previous examples inefficient for what I needed.

If you subclass your ViewPager, you can respond to the `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` methods of the `ViewPager`

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean wasSwipeToRight = this.wasSwipeToRightEvent(event));
    // Do what you want here with left/right swipe

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean wasSwipeToRight = this.wasSwipeToRightEvent(event));
    // Do what you want here with left/right swipe

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Here is the method which is called to determine the direction of the event.

```
// Stores the starting X position of the ACTION_DOWN event
float downX;

/**
 * Checks the X position value of the event and compares it to
 * previous MotionEvents. Returns a true/false value based on if the 
 * event was an swipe to the right or a swipe to the left.
 *
 * @param event -   Motion Event triggered by the ViewPager
 * @return      -   True if the swipe was from left to right. False otherwise
 */
private boolean wasSwipeToRightEvent(MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = event.getX();
            return false;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return downX - event.getX() > 0;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: downX is always returns 0.0 for me

Comment: @Roon13 is `event.getX()` returning a value when you touch the screen?

Answer (score 9):

This is simple enough with the introduction of an instance variable to keep track of the current page.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int currentPosition;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Do trivial stuff
        .
        .
        .
        viewPager.setOnClickListener(this); // doesnt have to be in onCreate
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(currentPosition < position) {
            // handle swipe LEFT
        } else if(currentPosition > position){
            // handle swipe RIGHT
        }
        currentPosition = position; // Update current position
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the `onPageSelected(int position)` method of [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). The `position` gives the index of newly selected page. If you keep a track of the current page index, then you can compare it against the `position` index to get the left/right direction of the swipe.

Now that you mention OnPageChangeListener doesn't help, consider the `onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)` method of `ViewPager`. Take into consideration the MotionEvent's ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can build a listener like this:

```
buttonIcons.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downX = event.getX();

                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                upX = event.getX();
                final float deltaX = downX - upX;

                if (deltaX > 0 && deltaX > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {

                    final Animation loadInAnimation = AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(
                                    activity.this,
                                    R.anim.slide_in_right);
                    final Animation loadOutAnimation = AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(
                                    activity.this,
                                    R.anim.slide_out_left);

                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(loadInAnimation);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(loadOutAnimation);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();

                    startSaveButtonAnimation();

                }
                if (deltaX < 0 && -deltaX > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {

                    final Animation loadInAnimation = AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(
                                    activity.this,
                                    R.anim.slide_in_left);
                    final Animation loadOutAnimation = AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(
                                    activity.this,
                                    R.anim.slide_out_right);

                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(loadInAnimation);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(loadOutAnimation);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();

                    startSaveButtonAnimation();

                }
                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It worked!. I've been struggling with it for a long time!.

Answer (score 3):

I use this small implementation to detect if the user is scrolling to the right or to the left during the scrolling itself. I might have some bugs during certain conditions that I am not aware of but it is what I could come up with for what I needed without having to add a touch listener :

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        int SCROLLING_RIGHT = 0;
        int SCROLLING_LEFT = 1;
        int SCROLLING_UNDETERMINED = 2;

        int currentScrollDirection = 2;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            if (isScrollDirectionUndetermined()){
                setScrollingDirection(positionOffset);
            }



            if (isScrollingLeft()){
                Log.i("TabLayout","Scrolling LEFT");
            }
            if (isScrollingRight()){
                Log.i("TabLayout","Scrolling RIGHT");

            }

        }

        private void setScrollingDirection(float positionOffset){
            if ((1-positionOffset)>= 0.5){
                this.currentScrollDirection = SCROLLING_RIGHT;
            }
            else if ((1-positionOffset)<= 0.5){
                this.currentScrollDirection =  SCROLLING_LEFT;
            }
        }

        private boolean isScrollDirectionUndetermined(){
            return currentScrollDirection == SCROLLING_UNDETERMINED;
        }

        private boolean isScrollingRight(){
            return currentScrollDirection == SCROLLING_RIGHT;
        }

        private boolean isScrollingLeft(){
            return currentScrollDirection == SCROLLING_LEFT;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                this.currentScrollDirection = SCROLLING_UNDETERMINED;
            }
        }

    });
```

We can detect the scroll direction because when the user is scrolling from left to right the `positionOffset` goes from 0 -> 1 and when scrolling from right to left it goes from 1 -> 0. We can then check that value once at the very beginning of a scroll and reset the flag only at the end of the scroll.

We set the `currentScrollDirection` to undetermined at position idle instead of `onPageSelected` because `onPageSelected` can get called if the user releases in the middle of a scroll and then you would get a false reading.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can find direction from using parameters of `onPageScrolled`.
Following listener is set to show log message once per direction of net fragment change ( left if left fragments reveals, center if no fragment reveals, right if right fragment reveals).
Class variables, need to keep track

```
    // -1 - left, 0 - center, 1 - right
    private int scroll = 0; 
    // set only on `onPageSelected` use it in `onPageScrolled` 
    // if currentPage < page - we swipe from left to right
    // if currentPage == page - we swipe from right to left  or centered
    private int currentPage = 0; 
    // if currentPage < page offset goes from `screen width` to `0`
    // as you reveal right fragment. 
    // if currentPage == page , offset goes from `0` to `screen width`
    // as you reveal right fragment
    // You can use it to see 
    //if user continue to reveal next fragment or moves it back
    private int currentOffset = 0;
    // behaves similar to offset in range `[0..1)`
    private float currentScale = 0;
```

The listener

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(
            new OnPageChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int page, float scale, int offset){


                    if(scale != 0f && offset > 10){


                        if(currentOffset > offset && currentScale > scale && (page + 1) == currentPage){


                            if(scroll != -1){
                                newImageSet = true;
                                scroll = -1;
                                Log.e("scroll", "left");
                            }
                        } else if(currentOffset < offset && currentScale < scale && page == currentPage){


                            if(scroll != 1){
                                newImageSet = true;
                                scroll = 1;
                                Log.e("scroll", "right");

                            }
                        }
                        currentOffset = offset;
                        currentScale = scale;



                }


                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int i){
                    Log.e("scroll","centre");
                    // we are centerd, reset class variables
                    currentPage = i;
                    currentScale = 0;
                    currentOffset = 0;
                    scroll = 0;


                }


                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i){

                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an OnPageChangeListner to the ViewPager and do something like this:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        float tempPositionOffset = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 0) {
                if (tempPositionOffset < positionOffset) {
                    Log.d("eric", "scrolling left ...");
                } else {
                    Log.d("eric", "scrolling right ...");
                }

                tempPositionOffset = positionOffset;

           Log.d("eric", "position " + position + "; " + " positionOffset " + positionOffset + "; " + " positionOffsetPixels " + positionOffsetPixels + ";");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

By using Kotlin and ViewPager2, this is my solution that you can register the OnPageChangeCallback listener as the snippet below (Swipe right only)

```
val pager = rootView.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager).apply {
        registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : OnPageChangeCallback(){
            var oldPosition = 0
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
                if (position < oldPosition) {
                    setCurrentItem(oldPosition, false)
                } else {
                    oldPosition = position
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnPageChangeListener()` and implement properly `onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)`.

You can detect direction by positionOffset and position variable:

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
{
   if(position == mCurrentPosition && positionOffset > 0)
   {
    //swipe right
   }
   else if (positionOffset > 0)
   {
   //swipe left
   }
}
```

Comment: where are you setting mCurrentPosition ?

Comment: you can replace mCurrentPosition by yourViewPager.getCurrentItem()

Comment: No that does not work, viewPager.getCurrentItem changes onRelease.

Answer (score 0):

I made this class for ViewPager2. Just create an instance and pass it to `viewpager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback` and don't forget to call `viewpager2.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback`!

```
public abstract class ViewPager2SwipeListener extends ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback {
  private int prevPosition = -1;
  private int state;

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int newPosition, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    final boolean positionChanged = prevPosition != -1 && newPosition != prevPosition;

    if (positionChanged && state != ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
      if (prevPosition < newPosition) {
        onPageSwipeLeft(prevPosition, newPosition);
      }
      else {
        onPageSwipeRight(prevPosition, newPosition);
      }
    }

    prevPosition = newPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public abstract void onPageSwipeRight(int prevPosition, int newPosition);
  public abstract void onPageSwipeLeft(int prevPosition, int newPosition);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of last two abstract methods? Probably a hint or two should be added in comments or remove it if a dead code.